# Is a power analysis appropriate when the predictor variable is bounded between 0 and 1?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, p-value, statistical-power

I am doing a power analysis (PA) to find the minimum sample size to detect a difference between two groups (with acknowledgment of the theoretical problems involving using p-values, etc.).

The mean and SD of my predictor variable is a value between 0 and 1 (up to two decimal points after 0). The predictor variable is an artificial index - it is the number of pathogens an animal is positive for, divided by the total number of pathogens screened for the animal.

Now, if I was detecting a difference in, say, total lengths between two subpopulations of fish - maybe one subpopulation is much larger than the other -  the difference in the means of each group could be a number like 15cm, 23cm, 31 cm, etc. (Just making up an example, I am no fish length expert)

But for my predictor variable, which is bounded between 0 and 1, the maximum possible difference in the means is 1 (eg, group 1 has a mean of 0, group 2 has a mean of 1).

My question is, is a PA even useful for my question? Is it useful in a situtation where the range of the predictor variable is not continuous and infinite (ie, bounded)? Of course fish lengths are 'bounded' by the laws of nature/how large a fish can truly get. Maybe another factor is that in the fish length example, the predictor variable is a 'real' thing (length), whereas in my situation, the predictor variable is more of a made-up index.

Any thoughts on this would be greatly appreciated! I would also love to be pointed to any literature that discusses this topic. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, power analysis is absolutely valid in this case. It will work for *any* kind of predictor. After all, most predictors are bounded somehow by nature, and some can only take the values 0 and 1 (e.g., group membership indicators).

Your model will accommodate the range of the predictor by essentially rescaling coefficients and standard errors, and what is relevant for your analysis is in the end a dimensionless statistic like a t value (which is the ratio between a parameter estimate and its standard error, so it's "descaled"), or an F value (a *proportion* of variance explained, so again "descaled"). In either case, the range or possible values of the predictor make no difference whatsoever.